# Ubuntu Server 12.0.4 LTS cannot Load after fresh install but gives a Blinking Cursor Screen

Tags: installation

After installing Ubuntu server 12.0.4 LTS from a booteble USB created using Universal-USB-Installer-1.9.5.1.exe I removed the USB to allow it to boot from the disk. But it only booted to a Black Screen with a blinking cursor. Several reboots have not  helped. What should I do? I am new to Linux commands so give me clear step by step guidance. I do have another bootable Slax USB. How can I use this to get to the Hard disk?

Comment: format the usb to fat32 filesystem and then create bootable Ubuntu server usb through `unetbootin`.

Comment: Thank you Ubuntu has now loaded. Your suggestion has helped though it was not as straight forward as you put it.

Answer (score 0):

You must install ubuntu desktop, not server. Ubuntu server does not contain X packages (X packages are the windowing system)